# how to fix this error "App\Controller\CoreController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?

Tags: php, symfony, service, containers

i was deconnected any times at my application so i've want fix the problem but i've this error ans my folders / services was correctly configured. I would like to know if anyone has ever encountered this problem and if so how to fix it.

Services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

CoreController

````
    
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\Intervention;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Index;
use App\Repository\OperateurRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Repository\InterventionRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;


class CoreController extends AbstractController
{```
````

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/ and edit your question. Questions on stackoverflow need to be asked in english.

Answer (score 0):

I've fix with

```
        calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

in services.yaml

Comment: Glad you got something working but you really should not need to do that and it is not a 100% accurate solution.  Extending from AbstractController should have sufficed.  What Symfony version are you using?